# Generic Dictionary Search Function

Tags: c#, search, generics, dictionary

I'm creating a Generic Dictionary which will act like a Library which will be able to Add, Remove and Search for Book and I've got these functions down expect for the Search function.

The search function has two fields: Title and ISBN, I am able to search for books with the ISBN but for the Title I cannot.

Here is my Search Code:

```
private void Searchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchTerm = TitleBox.Text;

        if (ISBNBox.Text.Length == 5)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Book> b in books)
            {
                if (b.Value.ISBN == int.Parse(ISBNBox.Text))
                {
                    ISBNBox.Text = b.Value.ISBN.ToString();
                    TitleBox.Text = b.Value.Title.ToString();
                    chkLoan.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (TitleBox.Text != "")
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Book> b in books)
            {
                if (b.Value.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm))
                {
                    ISBNBox.Text = b.Value.ISBN.ToString();
                    TitleBox.Text = b.Value.Title;
                    chkLoan.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Searching Requires the ISBN or Title field to be filled");
        }
    }
```

How can I get my Search function to allow me to search for Title aswell?

And how can I go about searching for a Partial string? E.g. Instead of "Cool Story Bro" I can search for "Cool" and it find all instances with "Cool" in it.

EDIT: Using what I have learned here I have fully working Search Function :)

Comment: Obviously "cool story bro" won't contain "Cool". Did you try making your search term lowercase?

Comment: I have appended my search function to search for lowercase aswell now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Book> b in books)
{
    if (b.Value.Title.IndexOf(searchTerm,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >=0)
    {
        ISBNBox.Text = b.Value.ISBN.ToString();
        TitleBox.Text = b.Value.Title;
        chkLoan.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

[IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx) method gives the first index of given string if found, Optionally it allows us to search `CaseInsensitive`.

Comment: What does `CaseInsensitive` mean?

Comment: It will match even when string1 is UpperCase and string2 is LowerCase or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there should work. As Dark Falcon suggested try:

```
string searchTerm = TitleBox.Text.ToLower();
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing a detail in your question, but in general if you want to do a keyword search of both the keys and values, you could do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Book> d = new Dictionary<string, Book>();
//Fill dictionary
string searchterm = //get searchterm
List<Book> results = new List<Book>();
results.AddRange(from i in d where i.Key.Contains(searchterm) select i.Value);
results.AddRange(from i in d where i.Value.Title.Contains(searchterm) select i.Value);
//Print Results
```